# Serial Communication using MSCOMM32.OCX in Forms 6i

Tags: c#, vb.net, forms, oracle, plsql

I want to communicate Weigh bridge with my ORACLE Form serially. I have already import MSCOMM32.OCX in my Project and On Button Pressed I wrote a Program to Start Communication between Weigh Bridge and my form. I was stuck at GET_NUM_PROPERTY of MSCOMM32.OCX Package.

SO Please guide me and share your Knowledge with me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

class:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.IO.Ports
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Public Class CommManager
Public Enum TransmissionType
    Text
    Hex
End Enum
Public Enum MessageType
    Incoming
    Outgoing
    Normal
    Warning
    [Error]
End Enum
Private _baudRate As String = String.Empty
Private _parity As String = String.Empty
Private _stopBits As String = String.Empty
Private _dataBits As String = String.Empty
Private _portName As String = String.Empty
Private _transType As TransmissionType
Private _displayWindow As RichTextBox
Private _msg As String
Private _type As MessageType
Private MessageColor As Color() = {Color.Blue, Color.Green, Color.Black, Color.Orange, Color.Red}
Private comPort As New SerialPort()
Private write As Boolean = True

Public Property BaudRate() As String
    Get
        Return _baudRate
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _baudRate = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property Parity() As String
    Get
        Return _parity
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _parity = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property StopBits() As String
    Get
        Return _stopBits
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _stopBits = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property DataBits() As String
    Get
        Return _dataBits
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _dataBits = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property PortName() As String
    Get
        Return _portName
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _portName = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property CurrentTransmissionType() As TransmissionType
    Get
        Return _transType
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As TransmissionType)
        _transType = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property DisplayWindow() As RichTextBox
    Get
        Return _displayWindow
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As RichTextBox)
        _displayWindow = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property Message() As String
    Get
        Return _msg
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _msg = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property Type() As MessageType
    Get
        Return _type
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As MessageType)
        _type = value
    End Set
End Property
Public Sub New(ByVal baud As String, ByVal par As String, ByVal sBits As String, ByVal dBits As String, ByVal name As String, ByVal rtb As RichTextBox)
    _baudRate = baud
    _parity = par
    _stopBits = sBits
    _dataBits = dBits
    _portName = name
    _displayWindow = rtb
    AddHandler comPort.DataReceived, AddressOf comPort_DataReceived
End Sub

Public Sub New()
    _baudRate = String.Empty
    _parity = String.Empty
    _stopBits = String.Empty
    _dataBits = String.Empty
    _portName = "COM1"
    _displayWindow = Nothing
    AddHandler comPort.DataReceived, AddressOf comPort_DataReceived
End Sub
Public Sub WriteData(ByVal msg As String)
    Select Case CurrentTransmissionType
        Case TransmissionType.Text
            If Not (comPort.IsOpen = True) Then
                comPort.Open()
            End If
            comPort.Write(msg)
            _type = MessageType.Outgoing
            _msg = msg + "" + Environment.NewLine + ""
            DisplayData(_type, _msg)
            Exit Select
        Case TransmissionType.Hex
            Try
                'convert the message to byte array
                Dim newMsg As Byte() = HexToByte(msg)
                If Not write Then
                    DisplayData(_type, _msg)
                    Exit Sub
                End If
                'send the message to the port
                comPort.Write(newMsg, 0, newMsg.Length)
                'convert back to hex and display
                _type = MessageType.Outgoing
                _msg = ByteToHex(newMsg) + "" + Environment.NewLine + ""
                DisplayData(_type, _msg)
            Catch ex As FormatException
                'display error message
                _type = MessageType.Error
                _msg = ex.Message + "" + Environment.NewLine + ""
                DisplayData(_type, _msg)
            Finally
                _displayWindow.SelectAll()
            End Try
            Exit Select
        Case Else
            If Not (comPort.IsOpen = True) Then
                comPort.Open()
            End If
            comPort.Write(msg)
            _type = MessageType.Outgoing
            _msg = msg + "" + Environment.NewLine + ""
            DisplayData(MessageType.Outgoing, msg + "" + Environment.NewLine + "")
            Exit Select
    End Select
End Sub
Private Function HexToByte(ByVal msg As String) As Byte()
    If msg.Length Mod 2 = 0 Then
        _msg = msg
        _msg = msg.Replace(" ", "")
        Dim comBuffer As Byte() = New Byte(_msg.Length / 2 - 1) {}
        For i As Integer = 0 To _msg.Length - 1 Step 2
            comBuffer(i / 2) = CByte(Convert.ToByte(_msg.Substring(i, 2), 16))
        Next
        write = True
        Return comBuffer
    Else
        _msg = "Invalid format"
        _type = MessageType.Error
        write = False
        Return Nothing
    End If
End Function

Private Function ByteToHex(ByVal comByte As Byte()) As String
    Dim builder As New StringBuilder(comByte.Length * 3)
    For Each data As Byte In comByte
        builder.Append(Convert.ToString(data, 16).PadLeft(2, "0"c).PadRight(3, " "c))
    Next
    Return builder.ToString().ToUpper()
End Function
<STAThread()> _
Private Sub DisplayData(ByVal type As MessageType, ByVal msg As String)
    _displayWindow.Invoke(New EventHandler(AddressOf DoDisplay))
End Sub
Public Function OpenPort() As Boolean
    Try
        If comPort.IsOpen = True Then
            comPort.Close()
        End If
        comPort.BaudRate = Integer.Parse(_baudRate)
        comPort.DataBits = Integer.Parse(_dataBits)
        comPort.StopBits = DirectCast([Enum].Parse(GetType(StopBits), _stopBits), StopBits)
        comPort.Parity = DirectCast([Enum].Parse(GetType(Parity), _parity), Parity)
        comPort.PortName = _portName
        comPort.Open()
        _type = MessageType.Normal
        _msg = "Port opened at " + DateTime.Now + "" + Environment.NewLine + ""
        DisplayData(_type, _msg)
        Return True
    Catch ex As Exception
        DisplayData(MessageType.[Error], ex.Message)
        Return False
    End Try
End Function
Public Sub ClosePort()
    If comPort.IsOpen Then
        _msg = "Port closed at " + DateTime.Now + "" + Environment.NewLine + ""
        _type = MessageType.Normal
        DisplayData(_type, _msg)
        comPort.Close()
    End If
End Sub
Public Sub SetParityValues(ByVal obj As Object)
    For Each str As String In [Enum].GetNames(GetType(Parity))
        DirectCast(obj, ComboBox).Items.Add(str)
    Next
End Sub
Public Sub SetStopBitValues(ByVal obj As Object)
    For Each str As String In [Enum].GetNames(GetType(StopBits))
        DirectCast(obj, ComboBox).Items.Add(str)
    Next
End Sub
Public Sub SetPortNameValues(ByVal obj As Object)
    For Each str As String In SerialPort.GetPortNames()
        DirectCast(obj, ComboBox).Items.Add(str)
    Next
End Sub
Private Sub comPort_DataReceived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As SerialDataReceivedEventArgs)
    Select Case CurrentTransmissionType
        Case TransmissionType.Text
            Dim msg As String = comPort.ReadExisting()
            _type = MessageType.Incoming
            _msg = msg
            DisplayData(MessageType.Incoming, msg + "" + Environment.NewLine + "")
            Exit Select
        Case TransmissionType.Hex
            Dim bytes As Integer = comPort.BytesToRead
            Dim comBuffer As Byte() = New Byte(bytes - 1) {}
            comPort.Read(comBuffer, 0, bytes)
            _type = MessageType.Incoming
            _msg = ByteToHex(comBuffer) + "" + Environment.NewLine + ""
            DisplayData(MessageType.Incoming, ByteToHex(comBuffer) + "" + Environment.NewLine + "")
            Exit Select
        Case Else
            Dim str As String = comPort.ReadExisting()
            _type = MessageType.Incoming
            _msg = str + "" + Environment.NewLine + ""
            DisplayData(MessageType.Incoming, str + "" + Environment.NewLine + "")
            Exit Select
    End Select
End Sub
Private Sub DoDisplay(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    _displayWindow.SelectedText = String.Empty
    _displayWindow.SelectionFont = New Font(_displayWindow.SelectionFont, FontStyle.Bold)
    _displayWindow.SelectionColor = MessageColor(CType(_type, Integer))
    _displayWindow.AppendText(_msg)
    _displayWindow.ScrollToCaret()
    End Sub
    End Class
```

use:

```
    comm.Parity = cboParity.Text
    comm.StopBits = cboStop.Text
    comm.DataBits = cboData.Text
    comm.BaudRate = cboBaud.Text
    comm.DisplayWindow = rtbDisplay
    comm.OpenPort()
```